# Batch norm causes Inception model overfitting?

Tags: tensorflow

I was posting this as a issue in [tensorflow/models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/890) repo.

I was training [inception model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/nets/inception_v4.py) from scratch with my own dataset which contains two classes only, and I noticed that when I start to use batch normalization with use_batch_norm parameter, the validation accuracy was around 50% ~ 60% while training accuracy went to nearly 100%, this bad accuray was almost just guessing. It looked like overfitting, and when I turned off use_batch_norm, the validation accuracy went to nearly 100% soon.

So my question is how exactly batch normalization could be possible to cause that? Any ideas on how to deal with it? I tried bunches of hyper-parameters of batch norm, it seems not helping.

Thanks